Why does this <input>'s @focus event listener set the state properly only once?
Lit Playground link. Code copied below:
import {html, LitElement} from 'lit';
import {customElement, state} from 'lit/decorators.js';

@customElement('simple-greeting')
export class SimpleGreeting extends LitElement {
  @state() selectType = 0;
  
  private _onChange(event: Event) {
    const target = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    if (target.name == "date-select")
      this.selectType = parseInt(target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return html`
      <form>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="date-select" value="0" ?checked="${this.selectType == 0}" @change="${this._onChange}">
          Today
        </label>
        <span> 
          <input type="radio" name="date-select" value="3" ?checked="${this.selectType == 3}" @change="${this._onChange}">
          <input type="date" name="date-enter" @focus="${() => {this.selectType = 3}}">
        </span>
        <p> this.selectType is ${this.selectType} </p>
      </form>`;
  }
}

The @focus listener's purpose is to check the second radio input whenever the target element (date <input>) is focused (clicked or with Tab key, etc).
To reproduce the problem I am facing,

click the date <input> --- selectType is 3 and the second radio checked as expected;
then click the first radio <input>,
then click the date <input> again --- the state value is 3 as expected. However, it is still the first radio that is checked.



I tried on both Chrome and Firefox on Windows. Same result.
I made an almost direct translation of this piece of code into React, and the React component doesn't have this problem. This gave me confidence that the events or the idea have no problem, but I am more clueless why the Lit component acts differently.


Please edit your question and add in your code segment as text in your question.  It's fine to also include a playground link, but links and images are supplemental to the main requirement that your code is shown as text within your question. The reason for this is that links can go bad over time, and SO is meant to be a question / answer repository that's useful to future users. Also, some users may be blocked from sites external to SO, so having the code as text in your question allows them to easily copy / paste into a dev environment they have access to.

You are doing a boolean attribute binding for "checked" attribute, ?checked=${this.selectType == 0}, etc. Replace those with property bindings .checked=${this.selectType == 0} and it should work consistently.
The "checked" attribute is used for initial checked value, rather than specifying the current selected. Though according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#checked that's only the case for type="checkbox", and type="radio" should be controllable with the attribute. I'm not sure if that's a bug, an error in MDN, or I'm just reading it wrong. In any case, property binding works.
